# How to decode UTF8 bytes?

Tags: c#, encoding

How can I decode UTF8 bytes in a string in C#?

Example: Decode this input:

```
"Poluci%C3%B3n"
```

To output this:

```
"Polución"
```

Comment: Do you have the source array? You could try `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray)`.

Comment: That's not UTF-8 encoded - it is URL encoded (aka percentage encoded).

Comment: What you have posted are UTF-16 strings, since we're talking about C#.  What you want to do is urldecode...

Comment: @oded - This didn't come from a URL, although it is similar. I believe `c3b3` is the hex representation in UTF8 for the `U+00F3` unicode code point (ó).

Comment: @seldary - That would make it a URL encoded UTF-8 string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This encoding appears to be URL encoding (not UTF-8 encoding). You can unencode it with a number of different methods in .NET:

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode("Poluci%C3%B3n"); // returns "Polución"
Uri.UnescapeDataString("Poluci%C3%B3n"); // returns "Polución"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Uri.UnescapeDataString("Poluci%C3%B3n")
```

the problem has nothing to do with UTF8 though. It's just URL encoded.